# Python-Requests Post request failed with 403 Forbidden

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I was trying to use python-requests to login https://www.custommade.com/, but it keeps giving me a "403 forbidden error". I got the post_url and content of payload from httpfox

```
import requests

post_url = 'https://www.custommade.com/secure/login/api/'

client = requests.session()

csrftoken = client.get('https://www.custommade.com/').cookies['csrftoken']

header_info = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }

payload = {'_method':'login','csrftoken': csrftoken,'email': MYEMAIL,'password':MYPWS} 

r = client.post(post_url, json=payload, headers = header_info)

print r.status_code
```

Could someone help? I tried to login other website and this works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you would print the reponse text you are getting you would see that they print error to you that you are not accepting cookies.

When you are doing something like this - always try to simulate the browser as best as possible - that means you have to set-up all the headers and also do the steps the browser does.

So first open the webpage in your browser. Open the dev tools, network tab.
Now click on the login -> you see that the browser does request to the /secure/proxy 
So your program has to do it too. Than to the actual request. Ensure that your request looks so much as the request from the browser - check the headers. You can see that they send the token there. (btw they do not send it in the post data as you did in your script). Also they are probably checking some other headers, because when you remove them - it doesn't work. So easiest way is to put all the headers as the browser.

Don't forget about the cookies. But this is done automatically because you are using session from requests.

[image]

Anyway this is working code:

```
import requests

post_url = 'https://www.custommade.com/secure/login/api/'


client = requests.session()

client.get('https://www.custommade.com/')
r = client.get('https://www.custommade.com/secure/proxy/')

csrftoken = r.cookies['csrftoken']


header_info = {
"Host" : "www.custommade.com",
"Connection" : " keep-alive",
"Origin" : " https://www.custommade.com",
"User-Agent" : " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type" : " application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Accept" : " */*",
"X-Requested-With" : " XMLHttpRequest",
"X-CSRFToken" : csrftoken,
"DNT" : " 1",
"Referer" : " https://www.custommade.com/secure/proxy/",
"Accept-Encoding" : " gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language" : " en-US,en;q=0.8,cs-CZ;q=0.6,cs;q=0.4,sk;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2",
}



payload = {'_method':'login','email': 'sdfasdf@safs.com','password':'asfdasf', 'remember':True} 

r = client.post(post_url, data=payload, headers = header_info)

print r.text
print r.status_code
```

Print:

```
{"errors": "Oops! Something went wrong.  Please ensure you are sending JSON data."}
400
```

^^ Means the password is wrong